# MS Excel: how to use COUNTIF() dynamically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet to keep a log of faulty items. Every item is logged onto a separate row and there is a "Usable?" column for each item. This is what and example row looks like:

```
  Item   | Usable?
 ---------------
1 Item1  | Yes
2 Item2  | No
3 Item3  | Unknown
4 Item4  | No
```

The "Usable?" column has a dropdown menu for each cell to set its status to "Yes", "No", or "Unknown" and I use the COUNTIF() function to count the total number of each status. I want to have the count at the last row, immediately after the last logged item, i.e.:

```
  Item   | Usable?
 ---------------
1 Item1  | Yes
2 Item2  | No
3 Item3  | Unknown
4 Item4  | No
 ---------------
5 Total Yes: | 1
6 Total No:  | 2
7 Total Unknown: | 1
```

The problem is COUNTIF() takes a predefined set of cells and when I add a new row, COUNTIF() does not take the new cell into the count unless I modify the function.

Is there a way to make COUNTIF() include the new data without me modifying the function?

Comment: What about using a pivot table? That's exactly designed for the purpose you've described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:
`=COUNTIF($B$2:INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()-1),INDIRECT("$A"&ROW()))`
Write the status in the last Row (the one you want to count and you can change it without changing the Formula)
in the second Column next to the status same Row write the above Formula.
Column B is the status (Yes, No, Unknown)
Column A is the Items

In case you want to write:

```
Total Yes       2
Total No        2
Total Unknown   1
```

Directly under you can use:
`=COUNTIF($B$2:INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()-1),"Yes")`  next to Yes 
`=COUNTIF($B$2:INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()-2),"No")` next to No
`=COUNTIF($B$2:INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()-3),"Unknown")` next to Unknown

Whatever Row you insert it will be counted Even if you select Total Yes and insert a Row

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Reference Entire Column**

As a drawback, you would have to place your totals in a different column or sheet.

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"Yes")`

**Option 2: Blank Row Above Totals**

Inserting a row within a range will expand it.  By including the blank row in your formula, Excel will automatically add the new range to your totals.

Just make sure to insert on the blank row and not your totals row.

```
    A       B
 ---------------
1 Item1  | Yes
2 Item2  | No
3 Item3  | Yes
4
5 TotYes | =COUNTIF(B1:B4,"Yes")
```

Right click on Row 4 header and click "Insert".  You will notice that the `COUNTIF` formula will become `B1:B5`.